# how to use python re.ingorecase

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I had an earlier question regarding returning an original sentence irrespective of eh title or case. I have done some working trying to work this out and came up with this:

```
import re
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
def foo():
    txt = "Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized. Breast cancer is 100 times more frequent in women than in men.\
    Factors associated with an increased exposure to estrogen have also been elucidated including early menarche, late menopause, later age\
    at first pregnancy, or nulliparity. The use of hormone replacement therapy has been confirmed as a risk factor, although mostly limited to \
    the combined use of estrogen and progesterone, as demonstrated in the WHI (2). Analysis showed that the risk of breast cancer among women using \
    estrogen and progesterone was increased by 24% compared to placebo. A separate arm of the WHI randomized women with a prior hysterectomy to \
    conjugated equine estrogen (CEE) versus placebo, and in that study, the use of CEE was not associated with an increased risk of breast cancer (3).\
    Unlike hormone replacement therapy, there is no evidence that oral contraceptive (OCP) use increases risk. A large population-based case-control study \
    examining the risk of breast cancer among women who previously used or were currently using OCPs included over 9,000 women aged 35 to 64 \
    (half of whom had breast cancer) (4). The reported relative risk was 1.0 (95% CI, 0.8 to 1.3) among women currently using OCPs and 0.9 \
    (95% CI, 0.8 to 1.0) among prior users. In addition, neither race nor family history was associated with a greater risk of breast cancer among OCP users."
    words = txt
    corpus = " ".join(words)
    sentences1 = sent_tokenize(corpus)
    a = [" ".join([sentences1[i-1],j]) for i,j in enumerate(sentences1) if re.match('risk',i,re.I) in word_tokenize(j)]   


    for i in a:
        print i,'\n','\n'

foo()
```

How ever, i keep getting this error:

```
type error: expected string or buffer
```

How can I make it return the sentence irrespective of the case using Ignorecase?
Kind regards

Comment: `re.match('risk', re.I)` doesn't look right to me. What are you comparing "risk" against?

Comment: @kevin, sorry  ommited something in the code, see edited

Comment: You'd probably find it easier to debug the code if you used a straightforward `for` loop instead of a list comprehension.  As to the `TypeError`: note that `i` is an integer in `re.match('risk',i,re.I)`; you seem to be using it as the target of the regex match.

Comment: Thanks Mark Dickison